# How to execute java code from BPEL process

Tags: jdeveloper, bpel

I need to execute java code in my BPEL application, i selected java Embeding from pallate and in code snippet i wrote some lines as 
System.out.println("some information");
while deployment it showed me error as "failed to compile generated BPEL classed for BPEL process "Processname" of composite" class path setting is incorrect.

please let me know how to set classpath in BPEL.

one more thing i have not created any class yet, as I am executing only snippet i have written.

Comment: Can you show us the exact code block you tried to execute? System.out should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Executing java code is BPEL never a good and idea will most certainly break the default build.xml generated by Jdev. However if you do want to use java code, just make sure that all the class names are their fully qualified names. This [link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/integration.1111/e10224/bp_java.htm) may help.

Comment: Have to disagree. Executing Java is often the only choice, or you'd have to do even a basic tasks (such as adding an audit record) with a remote WS call. BPEL is such a limited thing.

Comment: I think you may misunderstand the purpose of BPEL in general. It is supposed to orchestrate your business components rather than have actual logic to take decisions and do any data processing.

Comment: The truth is BPEL is widely abused as the actual decision making platform. As a contractor I have to come in and fix/enhance those sorry projects. That's where Java callout comes in handy.